# how do I test router push from NextJS useRouter?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js

I have a componente that trigger a router.push('/search');

ex:

```
const BottomNavigation = () => { 
const router = useRouter();
    return (
     <div>
         <button test-id="searchIcon" onClick={()=>{router.push('/search')}}>Go</button>
     </div>
  )
  }
```

how I Test this component and the router.push?

I Try this, but do not work:

```
jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    useRouter: jest.fn()
  }))

  nextRouter.useRouter = jest.fn();
nextRouter.useRouter.mockImplementation(() => ({ route: '/search' }));

describe("The Bottom Navigation redirect to the page:", () => {
    it('Search', () => {
        const router = createMockRouter()
        render(
            <RouterContext.Provider value={router}>
                 <BottomNavigation />
            </RouterContext.Provider>
        );
        const searchButton = screen.getByTestId('searchIcon');
            fireEvent.click(searchButton);
            expect(router.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/search')
    })
})
```

error:

Expected: "/search"
Number of calls: 0

My createMockRouter is this:

```
 export function createMockRouter(router?: Partial<NextRouter>): NextRouter {
        return {
          basePath: '',
          pathname: '/',
          route: '/',
          query: {},
          asPath: '/',
          back: jest.fn(),
          beforePopState: jest.fn(),
          prefetch: jest.fn(),
          push: jest.fn(),
          reload: jest.fn(),
          replace: jest.fn(),
          events: {
            on: jest.fn(),
            off: jest.fn(),
            emit: jest.fn(),
          },
          isFallback: false,
          isLocaleDomain: false,
          isReady: true,
          defaultLocale: 'en',
          domainLocales: [],
          isPreview: false,
          ...router,
        };
      }
```

the Router Context :

import {RouterContext} from 'next/dist/shared/lib/router-context'

Comment: Try removing the `next/router` mocking setup you have at the top of the test file: remove the `jest.mock` call and the `nextRouter.useRouter` mocking. Passing the `createMockRouter()` instance through `RouterContext.Provider` should be enough to mock the router.

Comment: same error Expected: '/search" number of calls: 0